# How do I view an xml file

Tags: xml, web, xml-parsing, rss

This is probably an easy question for experts but as someone like me who is very new in web development I am really having trouble with this. I have some xml text like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<row title="Structural basis for NADH/NAD+ redox sensing by a Rex family repressor." link="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20513431?dopt=Abstract" description-__cdata="&lt;table border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1097-2765(10)00368-0&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;//www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/egifs/http:--linkinghub.elsevier.com-ihub-images-cellhub.gif&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1097-2765(10)00368-0&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;//www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/egifs/http:--linkinghub.elsevier.com-ihub-images-celloa.png&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;td align=&quot;right&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/entrez?db=pubmed&amp;amp;cmd=Link&amp;amp;LinkName=pubmed_pubmed&amp;amp;from_uid=20513431&quot;&gt;Related Articles&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Structural basis for NADH/NAD+ redox sensing by a Rex family repressor.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;          
        &lt;p&gt;Mol Cell. 2010 May 28;38(4):563-75&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Authors:  McLaughlin KJ, Strain-Damerell CM, Xie K, Brekasis D, Soares AS, Paget MS, Kielkopf CL&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Abstract&lt;br/&gt;
        Nicotinamide adenine dinucleotides have emerged as key signals of the cellular redox state. Yet the structural basis for allosteric gene regulation by the ratio of reduced NADH to oxidized NAD(+) is poorly understood. A key sensor among Gram-positive bacteria, Rex represses alternative respiratory gene expression until a limited oxygen supply elevates the intracellular NADH:NAD(+) ratio. Here we investigate the molecular mechanism for NADH/NAD(+) sensing among Rex family members by determining structures of Thermus aquaticus Rex bound to (1) NAD(+), (2) DNA operator, and (3) without ligand. Comparison with the Rex/NADH complex reveals that NADH releases Rex from the DNA site following a 40 degrees closure between the dimeric subunits. Complementary site-directed mutagenesis experiments implicate highly conserved residues in NAD-responsive DNA-binding activity. These rare views of a redox sensor in action establish a means for slight differences in the nicotinamide charge, pucker, and orientation to signal the redox state of the cell.&lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;PMID: 20513431 [PubMed - indexed for MEDLINE]&lt;/p&gt;
    " author="McLaughlin KJ, Strain-Damerell CM, Xie K, Brekasis D, Soares AS, Paget MS, Kielkopf CL" category="Mol Cell" guid-_isPermaLink="false" guid-__text="PubMed:20513431" FIELD8=""></row>
<row title="Antimicrobial tolerance and the significance of persister cells in recalcitrant chronic wound biofilms." link="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21235682?dopt=Abstract" description-__cdata="&lt;table border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td align=&quot;left&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1524-475X.2010.00651.x&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;//www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/egifs/http:--media.wiley.com-assets-7315-19-Wiley_FullText_120x30_orange.png&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;td align=&quot;right&quot...................
```

This is a list of publications for different people.I want to put it on a website, something like [this](https://web.stanford.edu/group/boxer/GFP_pubs.html).

I do not have any knowledge beyond html and css and some JS. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me how to go about this or if there is any online tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing this xml file, just open it in firefox or IE and you will see the tree of tags.

Beware: the cdata zone will appear as a very long unstructured text.

If you want to do something (processing, selecting, ...), you have to parse it. usual languages have parse libraries.